# Spring Security update acl when not owner

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to add an ACE to an ACL but the current user is not necessarily the owner of the ACL.
This results in the exception

org.springframework.security.acls.model.NotFoundException: Unable to locate a matching ACE for passed permissions and SIDs

How do I give the current user, or possibly a role, the permission to update the ACL ?

Comment: from SecurityContextHolder you can get principal object which will provide you all information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is give them the BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION

Comment: @arurh could you post an example of how to do that?