# Remove Spring ACL entries without ADMINISTRATION permission

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In the context of a Spring Boot application, I'm using Spring Security ACLs to enforce permissions on objects of a given class. The user who creates the object gets `ADMINISTRATION` permissions, and he can choose to give additional `READ` and `WRITE` permissions on that object to user users of the application. The target users can then see the objects that have been shared with them in their dashboard.

Currently, only the user with `ADMINISTRATION` permission is able to revoke the `READ` and `WRITE` permissions for other users on a given object, which is not very user friendly. I'd like to allow the target users to revoke those permissions as well, in case they're not interested in seeing a particular object anymore.

Unfortunately, this does not seems to work out of the box. Trying to call `acl.deleteAce()` from the context of a target user gives me an `org.springframework.security.acls.model.NotFoundException: Unable to locate a matching ACE for passed permissions and SIDs`.

How can I solve this issue? Things I'm currently considering:

- Insert an ACE with `BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION` in the context of the target user before deleting the target user ACEs -> seems to trigger the same exception.
- Temporarily impersonating the user with `ADMINISTRATION` permission while removing the ACEs from the ACL.
- Directly deleting the ACEs from the database, i.e. bypassing `acl.deleteAce()`.

Possibly related but it's not clear how to actually implement the proposed solution: [Spring Security update acl when not owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304044/spring-security-update-acl-when-not-owner?rq=1)

Comment: Hi, I usually do the second one in similar cases.

Comment: Hi @m4gic, would you like to post an example of how to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not provide you a complete example. The idea is simple: create an authentication object object that points to the proper user with proper roles and replace the old one during the operation. As I googled for an example, it seems I found the built in (and probably better, or at least standardized) way for  this: the [RunAsManager](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-run-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AccessDecisionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/authorization.html#authz-access-decision-manager) which is a [Pre-invocation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/authorization.html#authz-pre-invocation) Interceptor. You can decide permission on an object by implementing AccessDecisionVoter's vote method. AccessDecisionManager makes the final authorization decision.

Here are two comprehensive articles on AccessDecisionManager and AccessDecisionVoter:

- https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-security/custom-access-decision-voter/
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-voter